# How to troubleshoot pen drive mounting via File Manager in Xubuntu?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, usb-drive, ldap, policykit

I have Xubuntu 18.04 and I can't make pen drives mount when I click on them in the file manager. I get a *Failed to mount "PEN DRIVE LABEL". Not authorized to perform operation.* pop up error.

This is a fresh install. I believe that this issue is related to my LDAP authentication which I use for years, since Ubuntu 14.02 or even before. I have been using all releases (non-LTS also) of Ubuntu or Xubuntu and never had any problems with pen drive mounting. With 18.04 I can't make it work. I already know that without my LDAP configuration mounting pendrives via File Manager works fine. I also know that mounting the same pen dirves in the command line as root works fine.

I believe that my issue is related to some new (from 18.04 perspective) policykit incantantion that is not compatible with my LDAP login settings.

My question is: how to I troubleshoot the pen drive mounting process started in the File Manager so I can figure what I need to change (in my LDAP login configuration or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you have to modify /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy

in my case I change to allow_any yes /allow_any 2nd and 3rd policy and ldap users automount correctly usb's

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what I should do. Could you explain in more details?

Comment: what part you didn't understand exactly?, you open the file, look at the policy descriptions, something about mounting file systems iirc in the description, change the value from <allow_any>whatever</allow_any> to <allow_any>yes</allow_any>